# How to sign bitcoin cash raw transaction?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, bitcore, bitcoin-testnet

I have to sign a raw transaction on testnet whose hex is given below, I tried hard coding everything in transaction generate part, it is broadcasting properly.
but I have to implement the transaction and signature part separately.
 I am using bitcore-lib-cash package

`const bitcore = require('bitcore-lib-cash')
const txhex = 010000000139a7e6578a862a10151bdbe0ed4a833cd615273b0cd0ecda1616ee8407d7d8040000000000ffffffff0241010000000000001976a914f0ac6825bd05b406d5224eab0be73852a487e06c88ac94dc0100000000001976a914185ec62d62510d40795109e6484e0487c28a3caf88ac00000000`

```
const private_key = 'private key here' 
let transaction = new bitcore.Transaction(txbuffer).sign(private_key)
console.log(private_key)

{
"errorMessage": "Invalid state: Not all utxo information is available to sign the transaction.",
"errorType": "bitcore.ErrorInvalidState",
"stackTrace": [
    "Error",
    "new NodeError (/var/task/node_modules/bitcore-lib-cash/lib/errors/index.js:20:41)",
    "Object.checkState (/var/task/node_modules/bitcore-lib-cash/lib/util/preconditions.js:9:13)",
    "Transaction.sign (/var/task/node_modules/bitcore-lib-cash/lib/transaction/transaction.js:1077:5)",
    "/var/task/src/custody/utils/biputils.js:155:12",
    "sign_transaction (/var/task/src/custody/utils/biputils.js:167:6)",
    "Object.generate_signature (/var/task/src/custody/assets/bitcoincash.js:220:23)",
    "<anonymous>",
    "process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)"
]
```

}

Answer (score -1):

### UPDATE

I just checked the source code of bitcore-lib-cash, when calling a `toString` or `toBuffer` function, they don't encode every field in `input`.

Here is one of the part of process to encode `input`:

```
Input.prototype.toBufferWriter = function(writer) {
  if (!writer) {
    writer = new BufferWriter();
  }
  writer.writeReverse(this.prevTxId);
  writer.writeUInt32LE(this.outputIndex);
  var script = this._scriptBuffer;
  writer.writeVarintNum(script.length);
  writer.write(script);
  writer.writeUInt32LE(this.sequenceNumber);
  return writer;
};
```

So I think you have to rewrite this `toBufferWriter` function or parse every field in the txhex and rebuild the transaction again.

---

Your txhex is invalid.

After decode txhex, it should have a `output` field in each UTXO input object, that's where the error came from.

Comment: Ok, I get txhex (tx one, name changed) from here,                                               const tx = new bitcore.Transaction()
        .from(inputs)
        .to(outputs) // so what should I do, provided inputs and outputs are correct, because if I sign it here then its working

Comment: How do you convert tx into txhex?

Comment: After getting hex I applied .toString() and stored that value into txhex. In the documentation .tostring is overrided by .toString('hex"). If I will not do this then, dynamodb will give error in saving this input

Comment: @ErDeepakGarg If it answers your question, I’d much appreciate it if you could accept my answer

Comment: No, I did not understand your answers, when and where I have to call/apply this function? Also, I can sign the transaction during creation time, I get problem when I try to separate this. Or may be provide some working example?

Comment: @ErDeepakGarg I'll do that soon!